# How would I include the pre-defined moment locales in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, momentjs

I'm wondering how to include one of the pre-defined momentjs locales in meteor, which normally resides in locales/*.js, but including this per the moment docs does not work in Meteor:

```
<script src="locale/pt.js"></script>
```

How would I include the pre-defined moment locales in Meteor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When external resources (javascript libraries, css, images, fonts) are needed, put them in `public`. So in your case, I would put the file in `public/js/momentjs/locales/pt.js`. Then, in the file containing my app's `<head>` (`client/head.html` in my case):

```
<head>
  <!-- etc -->
  <script src="/js/momentjs/locales/pt.js"></script>
</head>
```

All the resources you add in the head will end up being inserted in the head **after** all the ones from meteor packages, so no need to worry about load order.

Comment: Agreed, for actual libraries and features. But in the case of a simple momentjs locale file? Seems a bit over-the-line. In that case I would at least integrate it in a "translations" purposed package

Comment: Well, it would allow to include the locales not from a line in some HTML but from the `.meteor/packages` file, allowing it to be compiled and sent with the initial script load. Thinking about it, sending this locale on page load may not be what OP wants.

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to include the pre-defined moment locales, however that has been answered as a separate question. Thank you for your interest.